# ASP.NET Control Data Source changed by another Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, listview, gridview

I have an ASP.NET Gridview control that allows you to select an employee.

The employee entity has a navigation property for group entity.

I have an ASP.NET ListView control that displays all the groups that an employee is in.

The SelectedIndexChanged function of the GridView looks like this

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DAL.SafetyContext sc = new DAL.SafetyContext();
        long empid = (long)GridView1.SelectedDataKey.Value;
        DAL.Employee emp = sc.Employees.Where(x => x.EID == empid).FirstOrDefault();
        ListView1.DataSource = emp.Groups;
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }
```

The problem is that I can't <%#Eval("Name") %> in the item template of the ListView because there is no data bound to control when the page loads.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Why can't you?  Do you get an error message?

Comment: Actually, I think I was misunderstanding the error. It was as simple as not checking to make sure the GridView1.SelectedDataKey.Value wasn't null. The long conversion of a null was what was breaking it.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an [EmptyItemTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.emptyitemtemplate.aspx) for your `ListView`.  That way, when there is no data, you can display content that does not try to Eval on the (non-existent) "Name" data.

```
<EmptyItemTemplate>
   <td runat="server">Nothing to see here</td>
</EmptyItemTemplate>
```

You can have it conform to the structure of your ItemTemplate, but just leave blanks / empty strings in all the places where you do databinding.

Comment: If I'm using a Layout do I need to have separate Item Placeholders for EmptyItemTemplate and ItemTemplate?

Comment: @SmashCode I have not used Layouts with the ListView control, so I truly don't know.